# JiglibX addition to existing project questions

Tags: xna, xna-4.0, physics-engine, jiglibx

Got a **very** simple existing project, that basically contains a lot of cubes. Now I am wanting to add a physics system to it and JiglibX seemed like the simplest one with some tutorials out there.

My main problem is that the physics don't seem to be working how I imagined, I expected my tower of cubes to come crashing down, but they dont seem to do anything.

I think my problem is that my cubes do not inherit `DrawableGameComponent`, they are managed by a world object that will update and render them. So they are at no point put into the games component list. I am not sure if this means that JiglibX will not be able to interact with them as in all the tutorials there are no explicit calls to add the Body objects to the physics system, so I can only presume that they are using a static/singleton under the hood which automatically hooks in all things, or they use the game objects component list somehow.

I also noticed that in alot of the tutorials they use the following when setting up the physics system:

```
float timeStep = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond;
PhysicsSystem.CurrentPhysicsSystem.Integrate(timeStep);
```

Would it not be better to keep a local instance of the created `PhysicsSystem` object and just call `myPhysicsSystem.Integrate(timeStep)`?

Comment: Anyone got anything to add?

Comment: Did you enabled the physics for your cubes?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that your physics bodies are dynamic. Set 'Body.Immovable' to false. And as @Neil Knight said, you need to enable the body: 'Body.EnableBody()'